# How to append the count of numbers in each line of text using awk?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have several very large text files and would like to append the count of numbers following by a space in front of each line. Could anyone kindly suggest how to do it efficiently using Awk?

Input:

```
10 109 120 200 1148 1210 1500 5201
9 139 1239 1439 6551
199 5693 5695
```

Desired Output:

```
8 10 109 120 200 1148 1210 1500 5201
5 9 139 1239 1439 6551
3 199 5693 5695
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work for you:

```
awk '{$0=NF FS $0}7' file
```

Comment: Both of the answers worked well :) Could you kindly just explain the awk command in this case? Thanks.

Comment: which part was difficult for you to understand? @jmkam

Comment: @jmkam not-zero number will trigger awk's default action -> `print`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
awk '{print NF,$0}' input.txt
```

It says print number of field of the current line `NF` separated by current field separator  `,` which in this case is a space then print the current line itself `$0`.

Comment: Both of the answers worked well :) Could you kindly just explain the awk command in this case? Thanks.